# How to run a generalized linear mixed regression in r with a binary outcome and continuous inputs

Tags: r, regression, glm, lme4, longitudinal

I'm attempting to create a longitudinal model to predict risk of developing diabetes in the next year in subjects with various biometrics, namely BMI, Age, Systolic blood pressure (SBP), and waist-to-hip ratio (WHR). I'm using a fake test sample with two data collection times (years 0 and 1, which just represent years 2017 and 2018) and 5 subjects (ID 1-5).

I currently have my data set loaded as diabetestimedata (from a CSV file). I'm using the lme4 package, and want to use the glmer function since it is used for binary outcome variables (1 for diabetes, 0 for non-diabetes). I'm very much a novice at this, so I'm not sure if I'm inputting my variables properly when running my regression.

```
ID Year Diabetes BMI Age SBP WHR
1   1   0   0   24.0    60  140 0.90
2   1   1   0   25.0    61  130 0.95
3   2   0   0   20.0    65  120 0.75
4   2   1   1   30.0    66  150 1.10
5   3   0   1   31.0    77  160 1.20
6   3   1   1   31.0    78  162 1.21
7   4   0   0   23.0    51  125 0.80
8   4   1   1   28.0    52  145 0.99
9   5   0   0   26.0    54  133 0.91
10  5   1   1   29.2    55  145 0.98

> glmer(formula = Diabetes ~ BMI + Age + SBP + WHR + (Age|WHR) + (Age|SBP), data = diabetestimedata, family=binomial())
Error: number of observations (=10) < number of random effects (=20) for term (Age | WHR); the random-effects parameters are probably unidentifiable
> glmer(formula = Diabetes ~ BMI + Age + SBP + WHR + (ID|Year), data = diabetestimedata, family=binomial())
Error in pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GQmat, compDev = compDev,  : 
  (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
> glmer(formula = Diabetes ~ BMI + Age + SBP + WHR + (1|Year), data = diabetestimedata, family=binomial())
Error in pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GQmat, compDev = compDev,  : 
  (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
```

Errors can be seen above in the code box.

I'd like to have a regression output based on this data, but I'm really not sure if my inputs are really done properly.

Comment: it appears the relatively complex model you set up can not be estimated based on merely 10 observations... try to increase the number of observations, especially Subjects in your test data and see if/which of the errors persist